# Export to Postgresql ltree with Sqoop

Tags: hadoop, sqoop

To export my data from HDFS to Postgres I'm using Sqoop (1.3.0-cdh3u4). The main problem is that I have one column of type ltree.

```
ERROR orm.ClassWriter: Cannot resolve SQL type 1111
ERROR orm.ClassWriter: No Java type for SQL type 1111 for column path
```

Sqoop can't export even using --map-column-java to force String parsing.

```
java.io.IOException: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column "path" is of type ltree but expression is of type character varying
Hint: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
Position: 106
```

Any idea?

Comment: I've seen in Sqoop User group that they don't have a provision for handling non-standard datatypes, so I'll try to use plain text and make castings in my queries with text2ltree().

Comment: Did this work?  If so coud you pose as an answer?

Comment: Didn't work. We are not using ltree right now.

Answer (score 1):

Sqoop doesn't know how to coerce these types into text when importing the data into CSV.  You could add support for them in Sqoop...  or write a PostgreSQL query to do it: `COLUMN_NAME::text`!

```
sqoop import \
    --connect jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/foobar \
    --username ryan -P --direct \
    --query "SELECT id,ip::text,my_enum::text,description FROM stuff WHERE \$CONDITIONS" \
    --target-dir stuff \
    --split-by id
```

I also encountered `ERROR orm.ClassWriter: Cannot resolve SQL type 1111` with an INET field, and an ENUM.

Comment: My problem was about exporting, so I had no option to define the query. As you say the main option for this would be adding support for this type directly at Sqoop but I´m not using ltree anymore.